# Working VSC Launch configuration for renderer process? ("breakpoint set but not bound" issue)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

*VSC: 1.42.1

Electron: 8.0.3

macOS: 10.14.5

node: 11.15.0*

Here is one of the many [example](https://github.com/octref/vscode-electron-debug/blob/master/electron-quick-start-es6/.vscode/launch.json) launch configurations I have tried. I can debug the `main` process successfully but the `renderer` process has the "breakpoint set but not bound" issue so the breakpoints are never triggered.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
      "protocol": "inspector"
    },
    {
      "name": "Debug Renderer Process",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ],
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Also tried this example from Microsoft's ["vscode-recipes"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron) – with the same result as above: "breakpoint set but not bound" in the renderer process.

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "type": "node",
              "request": "launch",
              "name": "Electron: Main",
              "protocol": "inspector",
              "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
              "runtimeArgs": [
                  "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
                  "."
              ],
              "windows": {
                  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
              }
          },
          {
              "name": "Electron: Renderer",
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "attach",
              "port": 9223,
              "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "timeout": 30000
          }
      ],
      "compounds": [
          {
              "name": "Electron: All",
              "configurations": [
                  "Electron: Main",
                  "Electron: Renderer"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

---

I've been struggling for months with the "breakpoint set but not bound" issue when trying to debug the `renderer` process in `Electron`. I will spend a few hours searching around, trying sample launch configurations, trying various suggestions (e.g. [Electron main and renderer process debug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091899/electron-main-and-renderer-process-debug-configuration)) and then I give up, until next time. . .

It DID work in VSC 5 or 6 versions ago and then it broke. I've been all over the VSC github "issues" pages and nothing works. I **am** able to debug the `main` process.

My project structure is shown below. I am not using `webpack`, `angular`, `react` or any other framework like that.

Does anyone have a launch configuration that works wwith this sort of set up? "console.log()" is getting really old . . .

[image]

Comment: you should post your launch.json. I could at least compare it to mine

Comment: @pushkin - thanks for the reply. I've just posted two different launch configurations that I have tried (have tried every one I have come across). If you are using something different that works, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically exactly using your second launch.json from vscode recipes. I do now recall having similar issues and these two things worked:

1. Start the renderer with devtools, and then Ctrl+R inside the devtools to refresh it for breakpoints to start working. (though this will rerun the script in the renderer, which may have unexpected effects)
2. Start your app using the "Electron: Main" configuration. When you app has started, switch to the "Electron: Renderer" option, click the triangle, and from the dropdown that should appear in the middle of VSCode, select the one that lists your app name. Then, breakpoints should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Are you saying that you are using devTools and set  breakpoints there?  I used to be able to debug the renderer process from within VSC itself without any issue. I'll try your approach.

Comment: @NoGrabbing No, I'm still setting the breakpoints in VSCode. I just use the devtools to refresh the page (Ctrl+R doesn't refresh when focused on my app at least in my case. maybe you've set your app up differently so that works). you just need to be able to refresh the page through some means with option 1. When I've needed to set bps in renderer, I've typically preferred option 2

Comment: and maybe there's some github issue explaining this. because I do recall it working at one point and then it stopped